# php artisan vs apache/nginx for production

Tags: php, apache, laravel, nginx, vue.js

I just created my portfolio website http://ashishpatel.info  using laravel and vue-router, now i wanted to host it on aws ec2-instance, and we can do it in two ways.

1 - using php artisan,

```
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
```

2 - using apache/nginx and doing some change in apache2.conf etc.

I wonder which is best way for doing it for production for handling more traffic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `serve` command only for development on the local machine. Never use it on the production server.

For production, always use web server like nginx, Apache, IIS.

Comment: thanks, for prompt response, I was just want to know , if I can use it for production.

Answer (score 4):

Artisan is using PHP's buit-in webserver, which currently, can only serve a single connection at a time. This is not suitable for production environments.

Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

> **Warning**
>   This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.